# Remove "(or previously)" from "already voted" error - also: colour mismatch between errors

Tags: feature-request, support, vote-to-reopen, error-message

When clicking *reopen* twice, the following error shows:

[image: a]

The *(or previously)* sounds stupid, since that's just a synonym for *already*.

Clicking *flag* twice, doesn't show *(or previously)* in *its* error message:

[image: b]

Sidenote: why are the colours inconsistent?

Comment: The "or previously" is presumably a nod to expired/previously successful close votes, but it does sound a little silly. I *think* you can repeatedly flag after the active flag has been handled, which would explain why the flag message doesn't mention it.